# How to use realloc with double char pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, char, realloc

I'm trying to increase the memory by one row in double char pointer, but for some reason the program crashes, even though I don't get any warnings. I've googled and people keep offering this way to realloc, but it doesn't work for me. Do You know where's the catch? It's in the last line.

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define E 255

void Palindromas(char* Zodis, char eilute[E], int *kiekis, char** Ats);

int main()
{
    char Eilute [E];
    int i, kiekis = -1;
    char** Ats;
    char* Zodis;

    Zodis = malloc(E * sizeof(char));
    Ats = malloc(1 * sizeof(char*));

    // Failu aprasymas

    FILE *Duomenys = fopen("Duomenys.txt", "r");
    FILE *Rezultatai = fopen("Rezultatai.txt","w");

    //--------------------------------

    if (Ats == NULL)
    {
        printf("Atmintis nebuvo paskirta");
        exit(0);
    }

    if (Zodis == NULL)
    {
        printf("Atmintis nebuvo paskirta");
        exit(0);
    }

    if (Duomenys == NULL) printf("Nurodyto duomenu failo nera \n");

    while(fgets(Eilute, sizeof(Eilute), Duomenys))
    {
        Palindromas(Zodis, Eilute, &kiekis, Ats);
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= kiekis; i++)
    {
        fprintf(Rezultatai, "%s ", Ats[i]);
    }

    free(Ats);
    free(Zodis);
    fclose(Duomenys);
    fclose(Rezultatai);

    return 0;
}

void Palindromas(char* Zodis, char Eilute[E], int *kiekis, char** Ats)
{
    int i, l, j, index, ilgis, eil;

    for(i = 0; 1 == sscanf(Eilute + i, "%s%n", Zodis, &l); i = i + l)
    {

        *kiekis = *kiekis + 1;
        index = 1;
        ilgis = strlen(Zodis);

        Ats[*kiekis] = malloc(ilgis * sizeof(char));

        for (j = 0; j < ilgis; j++)
        {
            if (Zodis[j] != Zodis[ilgis - j - 1])
                index = 0;
        }

        if (index == 1) strcpy(Ats[*kiekis], Zodis);

        eil = *kiekis + 2;
        Ats = realloc(Ats, eil * sizeof(char*));
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you do anything else, you should search for *emulating pass by reference in C*. What do you think happens to `Ats` in the `Palindromas` function when you assign to it? How will that affect the `Ats` variable in the `main` function? Think about what you are doing with `kiekis`.

Comment: Furthermore, you are writing to `Ats[*kiekis]` which is *out of bounds* in the very first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Lastly, don't reassign back to the pointer variable you pass to `realloc`. If `realloc` fails it will return `NULL` and you lose the pointer. And *always* check for errors (such as `malloc` or `realloc` returning `NULL`).

Comment: Without the last realloc line the program prints exactly what I need... I'm just starting with dynamic memory, so I'm still a newbie...

Comment: This would be the reason why you always write identifiers in English: you might at some point have other people to read the code. If you didn't use English, you are pretty much on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use google to understand your code, maybe next time you can translate it for us.

I have a few observations:

- `if (Duomenys == NULL)` just print an error message, but doesn't stop execution. it should be like the previous validations (and better if returning an error code).
- `Ats[*kiekis] = malloc(ilgis * sizeof(char));` is wrong, it should be `Ats[*kiekis] = malloc((ilgis+1) * sizeof(char));` because it needs room for null ending char.
- `if (Zodis[j] != Zodis[ilgis - j - 1]) index = 0;` is fine, but better would be `if (Zodis[j] != Zodis[ilgis - j - 1]) { index = 0; break; }` because in this way the loop will stop at the first different char.
- `if (index == 1) strcpy(Ats[*kiekis], Zodis);` must be `if (index == 1) strcpy(Ats[*kiekis], Zodis);else --*kiekis` or else your `Ats` array will contain also not palindrome words.
- And don't forget to free each element of your `Ats` array before free the array itself with something like `for(i=0; i<=kiekis; i++) free(Ats[i]);`

Finally, answering to your question, to realloc the `Ats` array just do:

```
Ats = realloc(Ats, (*kiekis+1) * sizeof(char*));
```

I would reorganize your function like this:

```
void Palindromas(char* Zodis, char Eilute[E], int *kiekis, char** Ats)
{
    int i, l, j, index, ilgis;
    for(i = 0; 1 == sscanf(Eilute + i, "%s%n", Zodis, &l); i = i + l)
    {
        index = 1;
        ilgis = strlen(Zodis);
        for (j = 0; j < ilgis; j++)
        {
            if (Zodis[j] != Zodis[ilgis - j - 1])
            {
                index = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (index == 1)
        {
            ++*kiekis;
            Ats = (char **)realloc(Ats, (*kiekis+1) * sizeof(char*));
            Ats[*kiekis] = dup(Zodis); // dup == malloc+strcopy
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for Your help and recommendations! I really appreciate it. :)

I've already fixed all of Your observations from the time that I've posted the main question, however, when reallocating memory the program still crashes... I've googled the exact same way like to use it like You're saying, but the program just crashes when launched. :( I'll try to play with it, maybe I'll succeed.

Ats = realloc(Ats, (*kiekis+1) * sizeof(char*));

Comment: It's `Ats = realloc(Ats, (*kiekis+1) * sizeof(char));` *`*kiekis+1` and not `kiekis+1`*